# Fastest way to decide whether a phrase matches a query

Tags: javascript, string

Given a string `str` and a query `q`, I'd like to know whether every word in `q` has a word in `str` that starts with it. The case of the letters should not matter.

For example, if `str = 'Stack Overflow Is Awesome'`:

```
------------------------
query             match
------------------------
stack             true
sta               true
over              true
stack a           true
s a               true
a s i             true
v                 false
over c            false
```

It gets a more complicated when `str` has multiple words starting with the same letter. For example, if `str = 'Front End Or Back End Engineer'`:

```
------------------------
query             match
------------------------
f e               true
e e               true
e e e             true
en or en          true
b end end en      true 
e e e e           false
b end end end     false
```

What would be the best way to implement a function `isMatch(str, query)` that behaves this way, assuming that speed is the most important factor?

Comment: What have you tried?  As a reminder, SO is not an algorithm-writing service.  Do you have any initial thoughts?  How would you validate that the solution was the fastest?  Big O notation?  Empirical testing?

Comment: Aaaaaand...I just went and provided a solution.  I can't help myself, and now both Misha and myself should be slapped on the wrist.  Misha for asking the community to solve a problem for him, and me for complying.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is more important than memory, I would build a hashtable lookup based on all the words (and subwords) in `str` and then do the same for (minus the subwords) for `query`.  Then I'd compare the counts: if there were more words in the `query` hash than in the `str` hash, you can short circuit as there's no match:

```
function isMatch(str, query) {
    var strhash = str.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g).reduce(function(c, x) {
        while(x.length > 0) {
          if(c[x] === undefined) c[x] = 0;
          c[x]++;
          x = x.substr(0, x.length-1);
        }
        return c;
    }, {});
    var qhash = query.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g).reduce(function(c, x) {
        if(c[x] === undefined) c[x] = 0;
        c[x]++;
        return c;
    }, {});
    return !Object.keys(qhash).some(function(x) {
        return qhash[x] > strhash[x];
    });
}
```

In terms of speed, I am making the assumption that objects act as very fast hashes in JavaScript.  I actually don't know if that's a valid assumption, so of course to squeeze some more speed out of this, you would have to find a fast hash implementation.